# How to set up service account to run PnP powershell scripts from backend from Flow from SP Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, flow, powerapp

I am doing SP Online development with SPFx. I have some PnP Powershell scripts I want to run from azure, but I want the end user to be able to trigger it from a flow from triggers like an item create/update event.

I can create the flow, but the problem is, how is the authentication done for the PnP Powershell script? I want it to run as an account with full rights and not the end users rights.

What is the standard method for doing this? Do I create a service account without MFA and no password expiration policy and hardcode the credentials for the `Connect-PnPOnline` command?

Answer (score 0):

Never use "service" accounts. They don't exist.

I would suggest looking at Azure Automation. You can leverage a Client ID/Secret or Certificate pattern after registering an Azure AD app with the permissions it requires. Azure Automation can be kicked off by a Power Automate flow (there are actions available for Azure Automation).

Comment: I found an article on this https://spmaestro.com/sharepoint-pnp-provisioning-using-flow-and-azure-automation/, is this method what you would recommend?

Comment: Yes, but ignore the section "Create Azure Automation Credentials". The author describes the CID/Secret method of creating the connection which is what you should use.

Comment: Can you explain more about it? So I should ignore the "Create Azure Automation Credentials" section, but use the other method. Where is this other method described, Im not sure which section you are referring to.

Comment: The last section walks you through how to set up and use Client ID/Client Secret authentication - https://spmaestro.com/sharepoint-pnp-provisioning-using-flow-and-azure-automation/#site-script-trigger